# Counting Hamming Distance for 8-bit binary Values in C Language

Tags: c, count, binary, bit-manipulation, hamming-distance

I write a new program that compares 2 two digit unsigned integer. Compares by hamming distances. But my algorithm doesn't work perfectly. Can yo tell me what is wrong with this code :( THANKS A LOT!!

this is my counting method;

```
int countHammDist(unsigned int n, unsigned int m)
{
int i=0;
unsigned int count = 0 ;
for(i=0; i<8; i++){
if( n&1 != m&1 ) {
    count++;
    }
n >>= 1;
m >>= 1;

}
return count;
}
```

a and b 8 bit binaries.

```
 PrintInBinary(a);
 PrintInBinary(b);

 printf("\n %d", countHammDist(a,b));
```

let me show you output;

```
Enter two unsigned integers (0-99): 55 64
Your choices are 55 and 64
Number A: 00110111
Number B: 01000000
Hamming distance is ; 5
```

Comment: don't you need to shift both n and m?  Otherwise you are comparing the ith bit of n with first bit of m each time.

Comment: oh, i thought that one of them is shifting other one is stays same, too much calculate today, Thanks a lot.

Comment: `bitcount (a^b)` should do the trick. (for bitcount: see stanford bit hacks)

Comment: thanks for help but i don't want to use ^ :)

Comment: In that case you could use `(a|b) - (a&b)` _shudder_. or `(a|b) & ~(a&b)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put parantheses around n&1 and m&1.

```
if ((n&1) != (m&1))
```

http://ideone.com/F7Kyzg

This is because != is before &: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to shift `m` too to compare the right bits.

And you need to shift them regardless of whether the equality test passes. (move the shifts outside the inner `}` )

Comment: method and output editted, result is increased but not correct yet :(